# Difference distribution of two uniform multinomial distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I have two independent variables, $$X\sim Multinomial(N_1,(\frac{1}{m},\frac{1}{m},...\frac{1}{m})),Y\sim Multinomial(N_2,(\frac{1}{m},\frac{1}{m},...\frac{1}{m}))$$, assuming $N_1>N_2$

I want to know the distribution of $Z=X-Y$.

I think the answer is not $Multinomial(N_1-N_2,(\frac{1}{m},\frac{1}{m},...\frac{1}{m}))$, because $Z$ may have some negative entries.

I don't have a strong probability background so can't go further. Please help.

Comment: If $m=2$, this looks similar to the difference between two independent binomial random variables with different $n$ and the same $p=\frac12$  which you can certainly calculate but I doubt has a common name.  For larger $m$, each component would be the difference between two independent binomial random variables with different $n$ and the same $p=\frac1m$ (with the components related because their sum is $N_1-N_2$).

Comment: @Henry , thanks for your reply. Now I know how to compute the difference between two independent binomial variables with $p=\frac{1}{2}$. Could you kindly offer some intuition why for larger $m$ ,  each component would be the difference between two independent binomial random variables. And what's the two variable's $n$ parameter? Still $N_1$ and $N_2$?

Comment: Each component of the first variable is ~Bin$(N_1,\frac1m)$ and each of the second is ~Bin$(N_2,\frac1m)$